# What happened to Lablgl?

Tags: opengl, ocaml

Why exactly has the LablGL and other commonly used utilities ceased to support the newest versions of Ocaml?

(4.0.3 cannot compile it due to the lack of camlp4 support)

Is there any reason other than loss of interest that they have ceased to be maintained?

And are there any alternatives that are available that work now?

Comment: Unless you understand what you are doing, do not use OCaml which is not officially released yet. The latest release is 4.01.0. 4.03.0 (I guess you mean 4.03.0) is still far far away.

Comment: `camlp4` is distributed separately now (>=4.02.0) (https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4). There is an opam package for it as well. The fact you had to ask this question means you probably should stick with 4.01.0 (official release) as camlspotter mentions.

Comment: Lablgl doesn't need camlp4!

Comment: camlp4o is used in lablgl's Makefile, so it should depend on camlp4 `./src/Makefile: $(LINKER) -pp camlp4o var2def.ml -o $@`, and indeed `opam install camlp4 && opam install lablgl` works with 4.03.0 too. I opened a [bug](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/2261) about the missing dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your problem is exactly doing an `opam install lablgl` with OCaml 4.01.0 works fine here.

That said if you are interested in a more direct and recent, but less safe, interface to OpenGL you can have a look at [tgls](http://erratique.ch/software/tgls).